# How to get address out of the string?

Tags: parsing, geolocation, geocoding, google-geocoder

Here is the problem:

Let's say we've got string like `"Some restaurant is located at 750 17th St NW, Washington, DC 20006 and it's opened at 8am"`

Task is to get address out of such string. So cutted part should be: `750 17th St NW, Washington, DC 20006`. However - there is no fixed address format, no rules about it. Anything that is accurate for any map service should be considered as address. It can also be like:

```
"at 750 17th St NW, Washington, DC 20006 there is some restaurant and it's opened at 8am"
```

or

```
"there are many restaurants in Washington, DC"
```

My task is to get address out of the string and avoid getting out parts that are not address. I've quickly realized that problem is really complex. I could connect to some geocode API, but the string I'd send there still includes rest of sentence.

Do you guys have any idea or experience about such problems?

Specific language of implementation is not very important here.

Answer (score 0):

If the address's position in a string is not known, but the address is formattable somehow, then you can come up with some regular expression solution.

If the address's format is really subject to change and regular expressions are not enough, then supervised learning would be the solution.

Comment: I'd love to hear you're going to write a regex that matches all the expected kinds of addresses/location descriptions…